# How to make the input control remember the value I have inputed

Tags: html

In a login form, when I click submit button, if the submit is failed, the page will refresh and the content which I have inputed have gone, how to make the control remember the value I have tested and represent in the control.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For client-side it's more of a browser concern than an HTML concern.  Usually this is accomplished by server-side code which renders the page with the values in place.  What server-side technology are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way
With [this](http://code.google.com/p/cookies/wiki/Documentation#With_jQuery) plugin you can make it work.
Here are some of available API

1. Set the value of a form field or the HTML of an element to a cookie named
      after the field's/element's name or id attribute

   ```
   $('#username').cookify();
   ```

   The value of the field, or HTML of the element, with id "username" is set to a cookie
    named after the name or id attribute of that field/element. If a radio or checkbox and 
    it's checked, the value will be set.
2. Fill a field's value, or an element's innerHTML with the value of a cookie

   ```
   $('#username').cookieFill();
   ```

   Set the value of the input, or HTML of the element, with id, 'username', to the
      value of a cookie by the same name. If a radio or checkbox and it is checked, the 
      cookie will be set. If not checked, the cookie will be deleted.
3. Bind an input to the cookies library

   ```
   $('#username').cookieBind();
   ```

   Fills the field or element with id, 'username', with the cookie named the same and
      sets the field's/element's change event to fire cookify() to update the cookie when 
      the input value changes

Comment: Hi Sol, is there any general method, only use javascript not jquery?